# Parsing JSON using RubyMotion

Tags: ios, ruby, json, rubymotion

I have a RubyMotion class that reads from Twitter's search API to create `Tweet` objects as below.

When I run it I get this error:

```
(main)> 2012-11-08 17:01:32.634 Hello[39940:c07] -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xea1f800
2012-11-08 17:01:32.685 Hello[39940:c07] json.rb:20:in `parse:': NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xea1f800 (RuntimeError)
    from tweets_controller.rb:11:in `create_tweets'
    from tweets_controller.rb:7:in `tweets'
    from twitter_view_controller.rb:21:in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:'
    from app_delegate.rb:10:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
2012-11-08 17:01:32.686 Hello[39940:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RuntimeError', reason: 'json.rb:20:in `parse:': NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xea1f800 (RuntimeError)
    from tweets_controller.rb:11:in `create_tweets'
    from tweets_controller.rb:7:in `tweets'
    from twitter_view_controller.rb:21:in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:'
    from app_delegate.rb:10:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
```

**How should I parse the JSON?**

```
class TweetsController
  def initialize
    @twitter_accounts = %w(dhh google)
  end

  def tweets
    @tweets ||= create_tweets
  end

  def create_tweets
    BW::JSON.parse(twitter_search_results)["results"].each do |result|
      @tweets << Tweet.new(result)
    end
    @tweets
  end

  def twitter_search_results
    query = @twitter_accounts.map{ |account| "from:#{account}" }.join(" OR ")
    url_string = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{query}"
    url_string_escaped = url_string.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    url = NSURL.URLWithString(url_string_escaped)
    request = NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(url)
    response = nil
    error = nil
    data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: error)
    ##raise "BOOM!" unless (data.length > 0 && error.nil?)
    json = NSString.alloc.initWithData(data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  end
end

class Tweet
  attr_reader :created_at, :from_user, :text
  def initialize(tweet_result)
    @created_at = tweet_result["created_at"]
    @from_user = tweet_result["from_user"]
    @text = tweet_result["text"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: skip using Bubblewrap.

```
  def create_tweets
    json_string = twitter_search_results.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    e = Pointer.new(:object)
    json_hash = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json_string, options:0, error: e)
    json_hash["results"].each do |result|
      @tweets << Tweet.new(result)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I have accepted my own answer as it most succinctly answers my question.  Steve Ross' answer and blog post are brilliant and well worth reading though: http://sxross-blog.herokuapp.com/2012/11/11/how-to-build-a-twitter-search-client-in-ruby-motion/

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of CocoaPods that address this. Specifically JSONKit.

Edit: It's not a bubblewrap bug. It's a matter of interpreting the response from Twitter. I have a sample that does this with both bubblewrap and JSONKit. I'll put it on GitHub shortly. Short summary, Twitter returns an array of arrays. The first element is what's in that group and the second is the actual data. You want to iterate the outermost array looking for an array whose first element is results, then use the second element to derive your response data. Here are two alternative implementations:

```
def create_tweets_using_bubblewrap
  @twitter_accounts = %w(dhh google)
  query = @twitter_accounts.map{ |account| "from:#{account}" }.join(" OR ")
  url_string = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{query}"

  BW::HTTP.get(url_string) do |response|
    parsed = BW::JSON.parse response.body.to_str
    parsed.each do |item|
      next if item[0] != 'results'
      @feed = []
      item[1].each do |tweet|
        @feed << {:from => tweet['from_user'], :text => tweet['text']}
      end
    end
  end
  @feed
end

def create_tweets_using_jsonkit
  @twitter_accounts = %w(dhh google)
  query = @twitter_accounts.map{ |account| "from:#{account}" }.join(" OR ")
  url_string = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{query}"

  error_ptr = Pointer.new(:object)
  BW::HTTP.get(url_string) do |response|
    parsed = response.body.to_str.objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions JKParseOptionValidFlags, error: error_ptr
    if parsed.nil?
      error = error_ptr[0]
      puts error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]
      @timer.setValid false
    else
      parsed.each do |item|
        next if item[0] != 'results'
        @feed = []
        item[1].each do |tweet|
          @feed << {:from => tweet['from_user'], :text => tweet['text']}
        end
      end
    end
  end
  @feed
end
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for this and your write up at http://sxross-blog.herokuapp.com/2012/11/11/how-to-build-a-twitter-search-client-in-ruby-motion/